# How to manage concurrency for page blobs?

Tags: azure, concurrency, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I want to have multiple clients writing **to the same page**, and if a race condition occurs then I want all but one to fail and then retry (sort of like ETags on the entire blob).

According to this, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-concurrency#managing-concurrency-in-blob-storage, Put Page returns an ETag value, but is that only for the entire page blob? I think it's not for every page right?

Also in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/put-page there's a section "Managing Concurrency Issues", which says that ETag works well if the number of concurrent writes is relatively low - I assume this is because it indeed won't work on each page.

I am not sure which options I am left with? It seems all of the options apply to the blob as a whole. I high number of concurrent writes to the same blob, and low to moderate to the same page.

Comment: If you want to treat each page as a separate blob then consider revising your design accordingly to use separate blobs at your desired level of granularity. Then you will have the full set of concurrency options (ETag, lease) at the granularity you prefer. Otherwise, you will have to read back the page after each write to ensure that it was not overwritten by another client.

Comment: @MichaelRoberson-MSFT thanks - my main motivation for doing this is that it's fast to delete one blob - if I have millions of them the delete would need dedicated workers.. Table storage also has this problem.. I could have multiple containers but again that would require thousands of containers for my case

Comment: Millions of blobs in thousands of containers is not unreasonable. Same with millions of entities in thousands of tables. You get both the desired granularity and the easy deletion.

Comment: Somehow, I was under the impression that there was a limit on the number of containers, but there is not (ref https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits). So I might be able revise this, thanks.